# Want to make a application like one license per user in java

Tags: java

I want to make a executable jar which can run in only one machine.once it is run in any machine it can not be run in another machine.
Means i want to make one license per user type application.
I want to make this application using Java.
Any help on this would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the only way arround is to have a server that controls the application start.

Comment: will you have internet connection?

Comment: You should either change your title or update your question as one license per user is not the same as one license per machine. Although there have been suggestions on using a hash of some hardware information, I would not recommend to do that as the legit user might change some hardware components and therefore not be able to run your application as the hash will change with a high certainty. If you already use a back-end sever, simply use authentication mechanism to ensure that the user only started the app once. Here you could implement an annual subscription mechanism easily too.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's easy. Just grab your hardware informations and generate a hash. This will be synched on each start with a server. It will return a hash which can only be decrypted with the hardware. Then you can create a flag which is available by runtime that it'S "licensed"

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

Remember that JAR files are actually ZIP files, with a different extension. You can store other resource files inside a JAR file, and I believe there is a Java API for retrieving those resource files (I don't remember how that API works). So:

When your customer orders a copy of your application, make them supply hardware information (perhaps give them a little application which harvests the data). Build a JAR for them which contains a resource file, with a hash of the hardware information in that file. When the application starts, retrieve the hardware information and hash it, and compare with the hash in the bundled resource file. If they don't match, exit.